# How to attached documents (pdf/images) to Django emailer using the S3 URL to the document creating a file?

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework, email-attachments

I have some Images and PDFs, which are available via their respective S3 URLs. I want to attach these documents to the emails I am sending using the native Django Emailer.

Is there any way I can do so without downloading the Documents on the servers and then attaching them, as it creates an overhead od deleting the documents post Email sent.
Also, I don't want to give out the URLs in the Emails hence Images can't be embedded as a part of the HTML in the email.

Im using

```
Python 2.7
Django 1.9 
DRF 3.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your file is stored as a normal file field with s3 path, then you can do the following:

```
message = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, recipient_list)
message.attach(FILENAME, xyzmodel.abcfilefield.read())
```

**OR**

```
 from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
 try:
    yourfile = default_storage.open(files3_url, 'r')       
    email.attach(yourfile_name, yourfile.read())

except:
    pass
```

Hope it will solve your problem !!

Comment: The S3 url directly shows me the image, but I get a `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` with this line: `img_data = default_storage.open(img_url, 'r')`